# Hypothesis testing for a relationship, on a subset of my data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, clustering

Suppose I have a collection of paired samples $(X_i,Y_i)$, where $X_i\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $Y_i\in\mathbb{R}$.  We find that $X$ and $Y$ are not particularly correlated with one another, but when we divide the samples $\{X_i\}$ into clusters in a certain way (e.g. $k$-means), we find that there do appear to be correlations between $X$ and $Y$ when we restrict to subsets.  Are there any well-known hypothesis tests I could use to determine if this correlation is statistically significant, and that I haven't poisoned the well by taking too many clusters?  How about if $Y\in \left{0,1\}$?

A simple example would be to let $X$ be $N(0,1)$, and $Y=|X|$.  Then certainly $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)=0$, but if we restrict ourselves to the sets $X\geq0$ and $X<0$, then we find perfect negative and positive correlations.

Comment: Because the clustering does not depend on $Y,$ it is valid to include cluster membership as additional explanatory information.  Do so and proceed as you would for any kind of modeling exercise.

Comment: If there are many clusters, some correlations are likely to appear statistically significant (unadjusted p-value < .05) by chance alone, even when Y and X are completely unrelated across all subgroups.